# View States and Triggers

Tags: wpf, silverlight

Does anyone know if views states (used in Silverlight) will be available in next version of WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last I heard, WPF is going to be implementing Visual States (with the VisualStateManager) in the upcoming release.

If you're desperate and need something before then, check out the WPF Toolkit. It has the VisualStateManager built in (minus some of the functionality, which is expected since it's an out of band development).

[WPF Toolkit (via Codeplex)](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=25047)

Comment: i seriously wish they would go the opposite direction, adding triggers to silverlight.